# Exibir o resultado de um conteudo postado em uma tabela no banco de dados mysql onde o mesmo já tem seu css..mas ele não funciona no frontend

Tags: php, html, mysql

Como disse ai acima meu script funciona perfeito mas quando eu chamo no frontend

```
$_POST['descricao'];
```

Ela não leu o css que vem junto dessa variavel.

No banco tá cadastrado assim:

```
<p>Essa parte n&atilde;o &eacute; it&aacute;lico</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><em>Mas essa aqui &eacute;</em></p>
```

E ele não está deixando itálico.

Comment: Poste mais do seu codigo para ajudar...

Comment: mas está acima meu código é só a $_POST['descrição']; o css vem dentro dela que tá no banco.

Comment: Coloque o código html e o css com mais detalhes, não tem como por css no que vem do banco, podemos apenas trazer dados do banco dentro de uma tabela, uma lista que sej, e a partir disso montar o css na exibicição

Comment: Código que está armazenado na variável : <p>Essa parte n&atilde;o &eacute; it&aacute;lico</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><em>Mas essa aqui &eacute;</em></p>

Comment: cade seu html e seu css

Comment: Só queria que listasse assim como tá na tabela e o site lesse esse itálico .. entendeu

Comment: Já tentou <i> inves de <em>?